# Possible Session Key Security Weakness

Tags: authentication, hash, salt

I found a website that generates its session keys by hashing the userid (more or less public data) and the password together with MD5.

```
Sessionkey = md5sum(userid+password)
```

I am fairly new to this whole authentication topic, but I wonder if this could be a weak security "strategy". What are possible problems that come with this method?

Comment: Well, for a start, how about that it isn't a session key at all? The average user changes their password relatively rarely, and their username approximately never. MD5 is totally broken for [collision attacks, including chosen-prefix collision attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Security), but that's not necessarily a problem in a key derivation function (it depends very much on how the output value is used).

Comment: What Michael said.  If that happens as plain `http://website/somewhere/?id=1234&session=24305a42775afdd98e6626eadfa9edd6` and then the password in there is the actual password (not the hash of the password), then that's easy to brute-force.  But to make session keys in that way would be completely unwise 'cause it is vulnerable to session fixation, and retrieving the password from the session key would not even be needed.